# How to prevent unwanted behavior when a data member of a derived class inherits from a data member of its base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have an issue with the following class structure,

```cpp
class Base { int a; };
class Derived : public Base { int b; };
class OtherBase { Base c; };
class OtherDerived : public OtherBase { Derived d; };
```

The issue is that `OtherDerived` stores two instances of `Base`, one through the
inheritance to `OtherBase` and one from the inheritance to `Base` of the data
member `d`. I would like `OtherDerived` to store only one instance of `Base`.

What are the possible to achieve that while minimizing code duplication ?

One possible solution would be to use multiple inheritance:

```cpp
class Base { int a; };
class Derived : public virtual Base { int b; };
class OtherBase : public virtual Base {};
class OtherDerived : public OtherBase, public Derived {};
```

However, here, it might not make sense for `OtherBase` to inherit from `Base`,
we might not want to present the `Base` interface to the user through
`OtherBase`.

A way to solve the issue would be to use private inheritance:

```cpp
class Base { int a; };
class Derived : public virtual Base { int b; };
class OtherBase : private virtual Base {};
class OtherDerived : public OtherBase, private Derived {};
```

In this case, I'm wondering if it is good practice to use inheritance as a
substitute for a data member. I have been taught that inheritance of `Derived`
on `Base` should be present when “a `Derived` is also a `Base`”. In the
suggested data structure, `OtherBase` might not be a `Base`. Is my undestanding
of good practices concerning inheritance wrong or outdated ?

PS: I'm open to suggestion for an easier to read question's title.

Comment: Technically, that's what virtual inheritance is for, but the better fix is to avoid painting yourself in that corner in the first place.

Comment: For inheritance, I tend to employ the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) as my litmus test to see if inheritance makes sense.  There is not enough information in the code snippet to ascertain whether inheritance is warranted or not.

Comment: maaaaaaaybe `std::enable_shared_from_this `

Comment: Define your use case first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `OtherDerived` needs a `Derived` member, but not its `Base` part then there is something wrong with your design. It means that `Derived` is doing more than it should. Either it needs to have `Base` as base to be fully functional or not. It cannot be both. Use this instead:

```
class Base { int a; };
class Foo { int b;}
class OtherBase { Base c; };
class OtherDerived : public OtherBase { Foo d; };
```

And If you actually do need the original `Derived` elsewhere, it can be

```
class Derived : public Base, Foo {};
```

Comment: I might have been not clear. The issue is that there are two instance of `Base` in `OtherDerived`. I have no issue with there being one instance of `Base`, that's actually what I want.

Comment: @Poroing sorry I dont understand your comment. There is one instance of `Base` in `OtherDerived` in my code

Comment: @Poroing "I might have been not clear." indeed ;). Some context is missing, basically all one can say for sure is that your design isnt sound